# How to use SSRS to report using a custom, "matrix-ized" table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ax

First up, my environment: SQL 2005 + MS DAX 2009.

We have made a table that gets used in a matrix-like fashion for entering in purchase orders via an AX form. So each row will have:

- a column for item#
- a column for color
- columns 1-7 for size (size1, size2,...), quantity (qty1, qty2,...), and cost (cost1, cost2,...).

I am trying to create a report in SSRS that basically uses this data in a more list-like fashion for printing out a PO order form.

I have got it to show the sizing right, but the cost situation complicates it as the unit cost can, and does, differ depending on size (for instance 2XL is more than S-M-L).

For example in our table, item 10000 black has 3 for Small (this data would be qty1), 3 for Medium (qty2) and 4 2XL (qty5). The cost for qty1 and qty2 are the same at $2.50 (cost1 and cost2). The cost for qty5 (cost5) would be $4. I would like to have this broken out into 2 rows by the cost and associated size on the form. So one line would have 10000 black Small and medium info and the second row would have the same item and color, but only have 2XL and its cost data.

Is there a way to "match" fields or somehow cycle through them to get the correct cost without having to have an additional 7 cost columns? Or perhaps there is a more elegant solution that is escaping me?

Comment: Do you have some examples to make your question more clear?

Comment: This would be way easier with a picture, but I will give it a shot here shortly.

Comment: If you are at the table development stage still, size1-7, qty1-7, cost1-7 is a poor way of storing this information...very flat.  Can you change how you are storing this data?

Comment: We have a more traditional table structure that handles this, but the reason we did this is that our internal client requested to be able to create POs all on one line, rather than create a line per item, color, size grouping. Perhaps I should be using this one and grouping off those? I'll have to see how that pans out..

Comment: Clients requests like this should be considered for functionality, how the behind the scenes for this functionality should be defined by you...a view can provide this 1-7 design for them to view, and use a stored procedure that accepts the data on one line and populates the database accordingly.  If you let the business define your data model, 90% of the time you're going to have a single table with 200 coloumns in a traditional spreadsheet format :)

Comment: I think you would be best with 2 tables, one as a header for item specific info (colour type etc..) and a one to many relation to a detail table that holds 1 row per size/qty/cost combo (7 lines to reproduce the 1-7 functionality).